# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_FUNCTION in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, syntax-error

I developed a website using Wordpress on localhost and its OK when I uploaded it to online server using cpanel, everything went success but after upload, i am facing problem, error code is give below....

> > > Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_FUNCTION in /home/content/11/5033311/html/tarek/wp-content/themes/fruitsmile/inc/functions/close_site.php on line 10

and this is the code referred to in error....

```html
<?php
// Close Website
function get_current_user_role() {
    global $wp_roles;
    $current_user = wp_get_current_user();
    $roles = $current_user->roles;
    $role = array_shift($roles);
    return isset($wp_roles->role_names[$role]) ? translate_user_role($wp_roles->role_names[$role]) : false;
}
add_action('init', function() { << -------- THIS IS LINE 10
    if (!in_array($GLOBALS['pagenow'], array('wp-login.php'))) {
        global $theme_options;
        $site_status = $theme_options['status-switch'];
        if (!is_admin()) {
            if (get_current_user_role() != "Administrator") {
                if ($site_status == '0') {
                    get_template_part('/inc/closed');
                    die;
                }
            }
        }
    }
});
```

I cross checked my php code several times, it is correct. my code
any help will be appreciated ...

Comment: what version php on the remote server?

Comment: sounds like old php